# Difference between events and tags in xml

Tags: java, android, xml

What is the difference between events and tags in XML?

Is event like the big title and tags are subtitles?

How can I know which is the event and which is tag?

So in the code below, I'm getting events and tags from this XML file.

I see that tags are somehow buried in xml file as for every event, it is going through tags but I want to know how to tell the exact difference between the two

```
public boolean process (){
    boolean status = true;
    Application currentRecord = null;
    boolean inEntry = false;
    String textValue = "";

    try {
        XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance().newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();
        xpp.setInput(new StringReader(this.xmlData));
        int eventType = xpp.getEventType();

        while(eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT){
            String tagName = xpp.getName();
            switch (eventType){
                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                    Log.d("ParseApplications", "Starting Tag for " + tagName);
                    if (tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("entry")) {
                        inEntry = true;
                        currentRecord = new Application();
                    }
                    break;

                case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                    textValue = xpp.getText();
                    break;

                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                    Log.d("ParseApplication", "Ending Tag for " + tagName);
                    if (inEntry){
                        if (tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("entry")){
                            applications.add(currentRecord);
                            inEntry = false;
                        }
                        else if (tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("name")){
                            currentRecord.setName(textValue);
                        }
                        else if (tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("artist")){
                            currentRecord.setArtist(textValue);
                        }
                        else if (tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("release date")){
                            currentRecord.setReleaseDate(textValue);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                default :

            }
            eventType = xpp.next();
```

Comment: Sample code would be appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An XML file comprise of a set of tags, which should be defined using an XML Schema or DTD (old style).

Some XML Parsers, like the one you use, are event-driven. Meaning they read sequentially the XML file and they raised events when they encounter specific elements, like a start tag, an end tag the text within a tag. Through these events they signal to the caller of the parser where, in the content of the XML, the parsing has reached, and if the caller decides to do something with a specific tag then it will react to the event.

To conclude, events are raised when the parser encounters elements of an XML file, like tags. Tags on the other hand, are the building blocks of an XML file.

Comment: So you can get a tag to raise an event by setting the tag to be an event, meaning an event will be entered when tag is reached?

Comment: the parser is raising an event when it encounters a tag. A tag, by itself cannot raise an event. The event raised is the parser's way to tell you that a tag has been encountered, in case you want to do something with it. Also, the tag cannot be set to an event, there is no such relation between them, see it like this: a tag is a "thing" like gasoline in a car, an event is something that happened while you were driving the car, like you run out of gas.:)

Comment: Ohh so in my code event would be when it meets like the start tags, texts and end tags but the tags itself are what comprises the content of a specific portion of xml?